# How to add attachment of document with whatsapp sharing odoo 12

Tags: html, attachment, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am working on odoo12 and trying to attach document/image with whatsApp. Now i'm only able to share message(url link) with whatsapp and try to upload image also.

my code is below:

```
<a t-att-href="'%s?text=%s' % ('https://api.whatsapp.com/send', survey.public_url)"
   target="_blank"
   class="">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-whatsapp"/>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to send attachment on click for example adding attachment in my contact's form view then onclick the attached document will send? Or you're integrating it with discuss app?

Comment: only want to attach document on click. from above code it send message(text) i want to attach doc with message.